# How to fix the error of Malformed Line in source list in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04

I was trying to update my R in ubuntu 12.04. For that I entered the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then the following error occurs:

```
E: Malformed line 60 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Can anyone help me out of this problem. And also please let me know how I can upgrade my R to the latest version. Currently I am using 2.14.1 version of R.

Comment: What is the content of your `sources.list` ? We can't say anything about the error without knowing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the latest R for ubuntu 12.04, you must add the following line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` :

```
deb http://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/
```

Of course, you have to replace `<my.favorite.cran.mirror>` with the url of your mirror, such as `cran.r-project.org`.

More informations here : http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: thanks for response.... For upgrading my R I added the mirror to the /etc/apt/sources.list. After onwards this problem start occurs. I did the same as you have suggested. Do you have any idea about this.

Comment: There's a problem on line 60 in your file. Check it out, or paste it in your question...

Comment: Thanks Juba.... as I have already told you that Malformed line problem has been resolved and Now I have also successfully upgrade my R version to latest one. Earlier I was doing mistake in adding the name of cran. Actually there should be space before the version of ubuntu that is what I was missing.Once I did then problem resolved

Comment: I mean to say that I have resolved my problem that what I was getting when I was trying to update my R. And how I resolved already mentioned in my last post. Anyways thanks a lot for response and suggestions.

Comment: If you don't add / (slash) after precise, you will get a malformed line error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying the content, I think it is caused by some space, it is recommended to delete each space and then back to the space to try.